# To skip the elements using skipwhile

Tags: .net, arrays, linq

I am struggling to get the code right for my following requirement:

**Requirement**: 
To have the name of datacolumns from a datatable in an array Except the ones whose Ordinal exist in lstSnapshotExcludingCols i.e. a list of integers.

Can someone please help me in getting the expected results. I am using the following code, but it returns all of the datacolumns and does not skip anything.

```
Dim columnNames = ldtCurrentData.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
                  .SkipWhile(Function(column) 
                             lstSnapshotExcludingCols.Contains(column.Ordinal))
                  .Select(Function(column) column.ColumnName).ToArray()
```

I have the similar issue while selecting the data from a datarow:

```
Dim fields = row.ItemArray.SkipWhile(Function(value, index) lstSnapshotExcludingCols.Contains(index))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't user `SkipWhile(...)`. A simple `Where(...)` will do the trick:

```
Dim columnNames = ldtCurrentData.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
                 .Where(Function(column) 
                    Not lstSnapshotExcludingCols.Contains(column.Ordinal))
                 .Select(Function(column) column.ColumnName).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it worked for me.. BTY Any idea why SkipWhile is advisable in my scenario and what's the mistake in my skipwhile code?

Comment: I've been using LINQ for more than 3 years and have never used the `SkipWhile` method.  Tastes like implementation over policy, which is inferior to policy over implementation: tell me __what__ you're doing, not __how__ you're doing it.  If the answer worked for, please accept it.

Comment: I have the similar issue while selecting it for datarow. I have edited my question. can you please have a look?

Comment: I shall teach you to fish instead of giving you a fish: replace the `SkipWhile` with `Where` and negate the predicate.

Comment: thanks for providing the help, this is the first time ever I am using the LINQ & have to deliver the work quickly. That's why I asked, I still could not make it. It would be grateful, if you can help me out in that too please.